# I am making a counter in javascript. Can someone tell me how to 'loop' here so that the counter could increase everytime somone clicks the button

Tags: javascript

let count = document.querySelector(".count");

let dropBtn = document.querySelector(".btn-drop");

let resetBtn = document.querySelector(".btn-reset");

let addBtn = document.querySelector(".btn-add");

addBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {

let add = 0;

for (let i = 0; i  ; i++) count.textContent = add += 1;

});

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. You may use `Ctrl+K` to highlight code-samples in the question. I feel that one may not require a `loop` in order to increment a counter on button-click. May be consider a variable (say: `let counter = 0;`, declared at the script-level scope) that may be incremented on `addBtn`'s `click` event.

Comment: I'm not sure what the loop is for. Is your question "how do I add 1 to the counter when the button is clicked?"

Comment: yeah @Andy can you tell me how to do it. I am a lil bit confuse

Comment: you just need `addBtn.addEventListener("click", function () { count.textContent = +count.textContent + 1})` - the `+count.textContent` is because `textContent` is a string so you want to coerce it to a Number first

Comment: by the way `for (let i = 0; i ; i++)` would never do anything because `0` is `falsy` so the condition part of the for loop would be false, therefore it would never run - in other words, you don't even need a loop

Answer (score 1):

I like [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) for this. Your listener calls a function that sets up a default `add` variable, and returns a new function that acts as the function that's called when the button is clicked. This way you don't have any global variables. Basically closures are functions that carry the variables from their "outer lexical scope" when they get returned.

```js
const count = document.querySelector('.count');
const addBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-add');

// Call a function that returns a new function that works
// as the click handler
addBtn.addEventListener('click', handleClick(), false);

// Initialise `add` with an initial default value
function handleClick(add = 0) {

  // Return a function that is called when the
  // button is clicked. That function (closure) will keep
  // a record of the `add` variable,
  // and update the content with its value when the button is clicked
  return function() {
    count.textContent = ++add;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="count">0</div>
<button class="btn-add">Update counter</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let addBtn = document.querySelector(".btn-add");

addBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let count_element = document.querySelector(".count"); //select element with class "count"
  count = parseInt(count_element.innerText); //parse the text inside count_element to int
  count = count || 0; //if count Not a number, initial value of count is 0;
  count = count +1; //add 1 to counter
  count_element.innerText = count; //change count_element text to count
});
```

```html
<button class="btn-add">ADD</button>
<div class="count">NaN</div>
```

Comment: I did it before and it worked but it had a problem. I used to add 1 to the 0 only the first time after that it stopped adding.